# Parse Malformed XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a web application which a person scans a Datamatrix barcode into a form and this is passed via post to the next part of the process. I have no control over the xml contained in the barcode so can only work with whats there.
I cannot get the XML to load into the simple_xml_loadstring:

Here is a sample of the xml scanned from the barcode:

```
<xml><sc id="12345" ft="HS21" t="2016-08-31"/><pa l="MySurname" m="B" f="MyFirstName" s="Mr" h="1234567436" b="1995-03-23" x="2" a="97 the Town Road,Nowhere,My City" pc="RA 13762"/><pb i="4204" d="My Name" n="My Business " pi="Z008287783" a="Station Road,My Town, County, LAX 12344,028 45 67 89" pc=""/><dd d="Name of suff" q="120" sq="213325435436436" do="Directions" dm="425984002" u="80"/></xml>
```

This is my code for on the page which accepts the POST from the form:

```
//get XML from previous form field 
$searchTerm = $_REQUEST['ScanItem'];
$xml = simplexml_load_string($searchTerm);

if ($xml === false) {
    echo "Failed loading XML: ";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "<br>", $error->message;
    }
} else {
    print_r($xml);
}
```

I have also tried using:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $decodedXML = urldecode($xml);
```

Then trying to echo $decodedXML but nothing shows up after ScanItem=

Really really frustrating.

Any suggestions welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: what are you looking for? regarding what you need suggestions.?

Comment: In what way is that XML malformed - looks OK to me... ugly but not technically *wrong*

Comment: I need the id from the first element. I know its dosent look too bad as far as XML goes but it just wont load into the simplexml_load_string.

Comment: Your XML example is well-formed, and simplexml_load_string parses it without complaints. Most likely `$_REQUEST['ScanItem']` does not contain what you expect it to, so go _verify_ that first of all.

Comment: That XML seems to parse fine with SimpleXML - do you have an example that won't parse? See https://eval.in/633106

Comment: Maybe $_REQUEST['ScanItem'] is not the way to pass it from one page to another? any suggestions @CBroe

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is pretty broad - by default that fetches from `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` so that doesn't actually tell us where you're getting the XML from. You could store it as a serialized string in the session, then it should always be available.

Comment: If you only expect data to be passed via POST, then use $_POST instead. And make a debug output of the value, and check that in source code view in the browser, to see what it actually contains.

Comment: Ill give that a go...

Comment: Still nothing. I can see the post information going through though but not picekd up by simple_xml_load

Comment: Ok, so Ive now used file_get_contents('php://input'); which I can echo onto the screen, But when I use urldecode() it returns an an empty string? The string prints to the screen as: ScanItem=%3Cxml%3E%3Csc+id%3D%2212345%22+ft%3D%22HS21%22+t%3D%222016-08-31%22%2F%3E%3Cpa+l%3D%22MySurname%22+m%3D%22B%22+f%3D%22 etc etc (too long for comments here)  But then nothing returns when I try to decode it?

Comment: @shridhar Im only really looking to extract the value of sc id. thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for value 12345 ?
Then here u go..

```
<?php
$xml_string = '<xml><sc id="12345" ft="HS21" t="2016-08-31"/><pa l="MySurname" m="B" f="MyFirstName" s="Mr" h="1234567436" b="1995-03-23" x="2" a="97 the Town Road,Nowhere,My City" pc="RA 13762"/><pb i="4204" d="My Name" n="My Business " pi="Z008287783" a="Station Road,My Town, County, LAX 12344,028 45 67 89" pc=""/><dd d="Name of suff" q="120" sq="213325435436436" do="Directions" dm="425984002" u="80"/></xml>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$xml_id_to_sring = $xml->sc->attributes()->{'id'};
$json = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml_id_to_sring));
print_r($json[0]);
?>
```

[Eval Link for the answer](https://eval.in/633549)